# View Controller present portrait random

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I am presenting a view controller in landscape left mode. and its working fine. But i am facing a random issue where controller present portrait mode. I dont know why it is happening. i am using below code for rotate the view while presenting the view

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: Are you using navigation controller?

Comment: yes i am using navigation controller